# Spring Cloud Netflix - after upgrading to Spring Boot 2.6 getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jersey/client/apache4/ApacheHttpClient4

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

After upgrading Spring Boot to a newer version I am now getting this error:

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.eurekaClient' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/netflix/eureka/EurekaClientAutoConfiguration$RefreshableEurekaCl
ientConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.netflix.discovery.EurekaClient]: Factory method 'eurekaClient' t
hrew exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to initialize DiscoveryClient!
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:638) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$1(AbstractBeanFactory.java:374) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope$BeanLifecycleWrapper.getBean(GenericScope.java:376) ~[spring-cloud-context-3.1.1.jar!/:3.1.1]
at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope.get(GenericScope.java:179) ~[spring-cloud-context-3.1.1.jar!/:3.1.1]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:371) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
at org.springframework.aop.target.SimpleBeanTargetSource.getTarget(SimpleBeanTargetSource.java:35) ~[spring-aop-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaRegistration.getTargetObject(EurekaRegistration.java:127) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-3.1.1.jar!/:3.1.1]
at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaRegistration.getEurekaClient(EurekaRegistration.java:115) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-3.1.1.jar!/:3.1.1]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:282) ~[spring-core-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope$LockedScopedProxyFactoryBean.invoke(GenericScope.java:485) ~[spring-cloud-context-3.1.1.jar!/:3.1.1]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763) ~[spring-aop-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:708) ~[spring-aop-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaRegistration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e3fff6c8.getEurekaClient() ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-3.1.1.jar!/:3.1.1]
at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaServiceRegistry.maybeInitializeClient(EurekaServiceRegistry.java:54) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-3.1.1.jar!/:3.1.1]
at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaServiceRegistry.register(EurekaServiceRegistry.java:38) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-3.1.1.jar!/:3.1.1]
at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaAutoServiceRegistration.start(EurekaAutoServiceRegistration.java:83) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-3.1.1.jar!/:3.1.1]
at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaAutoServiceRegistration.onApplicationEvent(EurekaAutoServiceRegistration.java:146) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-3.1.1.jar!/:3.1.1]
at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaAutoServiceRegistration.onApplicationEvent(EurekaAutoServiceRegistration.java:131) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-3.1.1.jar!/:3.1.1]
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:176) ~[spring-context-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:169) ~[spring-context-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:143) ~[spring-context-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:421) ~[spring-context-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:378) ~[spring-context-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.WebServerStartStopLifecycle.start(WebServerStartStopLifecycle.java:46) ~[spring-boot-2.6.7.jar!/:2.6.7]
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:178) ~[spring-context-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:54) ~[spring-context-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:356) ~[spring-context-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:155) ~[spring-context-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:123) ~[spring-context-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:935) ~[spring-context-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:586) ~[spring-context-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.6.7.jar!/:2.6.7]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:740) ~[spring-boot-2.6.7.jar!/:2.6.7]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:415) ~[spring-boot-2.6.7.jar!/:2.6.7]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) ~[spring-boot-2.6.7.jar!/:2.6.7]
at Application.main(Application.java:41) ~[classes!/:1.0.0-497]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) ~[service-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0
at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108) ~[service-1.0.0-497.jar:1.0.0]
at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) ~[iservice-1.0.0-497.jar:1.0.0]
at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88) ~[service-1.0.0-497.jar:1.0.0]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.netflix.discovery.EurekaClient]: Factory method 'eurekaClient' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to initial
ize DiscoveryClient!
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
... 55 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to initialize DiscoveryClient!
at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.(DiscoveryClient.java:436) ~[eureka-client-1.10.17.jar!/:1.10.17]
at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.(DiscoveryClient.java:283) ~[eureka-client-1.10.17.jar!/:1.10.17]
at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.(DiscoveryClient.java:279) ~[eureka-client-1.10.17.jar!/:1.10.17]
at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.CloudEurekaClient.(CloudEurekaClient.java:66) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-3.1.1.jar!/:3.1.1]
at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaClientAutoConfiguration$RefreshableEurekaClientConfiguration.eurekaClient(EurekaClientAutoConfiguration.java:295) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-3.1.1.jar!/:3.1.1]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
... 56 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jersey/client/apache4/ApacheHttpClient4
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.jersey.Jersey1TransportClientFactories.newTransportClientFactory(Jersey1TransportClientFactories.java:59) ~[eureka-client-1.10.17.jar!/:1.10.17]
at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.scheduleServerEndpointTask(DiscoveryClient.java:528) ~[eureka-client-1.10.17.jar!/:1.10.17]
at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.(DiscoveryClient.java:423) ~[eureka-client-1.10.17.jar!/:1.10.17]
... 65 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jersey.client.apache4.ApacheHttpClient4
at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:471) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:589) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:151) ~[service-1.0.0-497.jar:1.0.0]
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522) ~[na:na]

This is what I had originally, that was working with Spring Boot 2.3.3:

```
   <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
   </dependency>
```

After some research some suggested adding this:

```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
       <artifactId>jersey-apache-client4</artifactId>
       <version>1.19.4</version>
   </dependency>
```

But.. why should I have to manually add the Jersey dependency? I am following the Spring Boot Version Train, so shouldn't this be pulled in if needed to run spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client?

Isn't the whole point of Maven and POM dependencies to list them in there, so why am I having to add this manually?

Thanks,
B

Comment: By default the eureka client now uses rest template rather than jersey. Can you add more details such as the full exception and dependencies?

Comment: Added full stack

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/docs/current/reference/html/#eurekaclient-with-jersey